# Hex values get appended to strings when outputted

Tags: php, hex, mjpeg

```
# Per-image header, note the two new-lines

print "--$boundary\n";


$file= str_replace("/snapshots", "", $_GET['src'].'?random='.rand(1, 1000));
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $file);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
$out = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);


print "Content-type: image/jpeg\r\n";
print("Content-Length: ". strlen($out) ."\r\n\r\n");

print($out."\r\n");
# Your function to get one jpeg image
usleep(500000);
}
```

And this is the response :

```
b
--my_mjpeg

1a
Content-type: image/jpeg

19
Content-Length: 11808


169a
......JFIF.............C..............................................!........."$".$.......C.........................................................................@.
```

Comment: Looks like the result of a `transfer-encoding: chunked`, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding  and http://docs.php.net/function.header

Comment: Sorry , but i don't understand. Only i need delete the hexa in the string .This is a script to generate a mjpeg.how i do the implemetation for the chunk transfer ?

Comment: And this code in my localhost working fine , but in the server of production not. is strange